# Expose an object's member functions as global functions

Tags: javascript, rhino, nashorn

For example I have:

```
var n = {
  abc: function() { print("abc"); },
  def: function() { print("def"); },
};
```

Is there a way to export `abc` and `def` as global functions, so that I can call `abc()` directly rather than `n.abc()`?

My context for this is using Rhino/Nashorn script engine, and I'd like to inject a "global" object that provides global functions.

Comment: Depending on the environment, you may be able to do `var abc = n.abc;`, or `global.abc = n.abc`, or `var abc = n.abc; export {abc};`, or `exports.abc = n.abc`, or several other variations.

Comment: thanks, it looks like global is the one I'm looking for! I'd still need to find another way to iterate through n to list out all keys -- somehow for (key in n) {...} does not work if n is injected from Java outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use JavaScript's `bind`, `call` and `apply` methods to call the object's member functions when you need to invoke them? Making them global indicates code smell.

Comment: thanks, bind sounds very promising. call and apply seems an overkill, since the goal of "exporting" was to simplify the script written. Code smell is not a problem since the functions exposed could be well controlled from the Java outside.

Answer (score 3):

The answers for Rhino and Nashorn would be different.

For Rhino, when you create the global object using `Context.initStandardObjects`, you can then add your properties on the Java side by calling `ScriptableObject.defineProperty` (see [Rhino API](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptableObject.html)) and then the properties will be added to that global scope. If you need a property of type `function` as your example shows, create it using the [FunctionObject API](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/FunctionObject.html).

For Nashorn, you can use the interfaces mostly based on the standard `javax.script` APIs, with a couple of Nashorn-specific extensions. When evaluating your script, first use `ScriptEngine.createBindings()` to create a Bindings object, then use `Bindings.put` to use `eval(String/Reader,Bindings)`

If you need a function property, then on the Java side call [ScriptUtils.wrap](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~sundar/jdk.nashorn.api/8u20/javadoc/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptUtils.html#wrap-java.lang.Object-) to create a `ScriptObjectMirror` (make sure to cast it to that; return type of the method is `Object`), then call `get([function name])` to get an executable function property, then put that in the global scope.

All of that said, it seems to me that this is more easily handled on the script side using:

```
var abc = function() { return n.abc.apply(n,arguments); };
```

That's portable across Rhino/Nashorn and is one line, which is a lot less work than what you're going to do if you want to avoid writing that one line.

If you execute that in the global scope, you don't need a qualifier; it'll be added to the top-level object as a property. If you want to be more explicit you can do something like this:

```
(function() {
    var global = this; // inner functions called without target default to global as 'this'
    this.abc = function() { return n.abc.apply(n,arguments); };
})();
```

... which will work unless you start doing stuff that's a lot fancier (like messing around with 'this' values when loading scripts).

Comment: That's what I was after. But somehow I hit on a block: `Caused by: <eval>:3 TypeError: [jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.SimpleDynamicMethod void ScriptProxy.load(String)] has no such function "apply"`. It looks like the member methods of the injected object are different from the regular javascript functions. Do you know a way to get the injected wrapped to act like a regular javascript function? Or converted?

Comment: Can you describe more thoroughly what you did which resulted in the error?

Comment: So, in Java, `scriptEngine.put("w", new ScriptProxy());`, and then eval `this["load"] = w.load.bind(w);` and that gave the 'no such function' error.